# Exporting Google colab output as a screenshot and save to my mounted drive

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, screenshot

I have written a google colab py3 script which shows some colorful table as `output`:

[image]

I just want to export the `output` as a PNG image and save it to my google drive.

Any idea how can I do it?